Event Calendar?
Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.8, PHP 8.1, hosted on Linode.
When we first started using CIVICRM, we used the Event Calendar app successfully.  When we upgraded to 5.67.1, that app no longer functioned under the upgrade. Is there a new Event Calendar app that is functional under the later releases?  What workarounds are folks using to get a calendar for people to use versus just having a listing of events?  Are there integrations that we can use to show and use a calendar?

Hi Margaret - there are multiple event calendar apps, so editing your question to specify which you're using would be helpful.  Also, could you say more about "no longer functioned"?  Does it have an error? Does it not show anything at all? Does it show the wrong data?

Which Event calendar app your using? You can use https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.eventcalendar
